# While loop, doesn't seem to do anything?

Tags: c++, loops, operators, iteration, while-loop

Hi there i'm trying to make a function in C++ that takes a number, i, and decides if it is a prime number or not by running through a loop to find it's multiples, and then makes sure it isn't prime through a series of test. However, it seems the loop isn't even being run through. I've told it to output no matter where in the loop it is, but I get no outputs. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int j =1;
    int z = 0;
    int i = 10;
    bool p = false;
    while (p = false){
        cout << "not starting ifs";
        z=i%j;
        if (z==0 && j>2){
        p=true;
        cout << "not prime" << endl << "loops to if";
        }
        else if (j==1){
            j++;
            cout <<"loops to else if 1";
            }
        else if ( i==2 || j==i ){
          p = true;
          cout << "prime" << endl << "loops to else if 2";
            }
            else {
            j++;
            cout << "loops to else";
                }
        }
            return 0;
}
```

I don't care whether or not the math behind it is right, I want to figure that out myself for the learning experience. But if anyone could help me figure this out with a good easy to understand explanation I would appreciate it! I"m really new to programming, so I'm not used to jargon yet. I look forward to your advice!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using `=` instead of `==` in

```
while (p = false){
```

When you do that, you assign `false` to `p` and the result of the expression is `false` which gets tested in the `while` loop resulting in exiting of the loop.

Comment: Samuraisoulification - don't forget to accept whichever answer you went with!

Comment: I will, but currently it says I have to wait 10 minutes.

Answer (score 8):

Better yet,

```
while(!p)
```

After all, that's what the operator is for.

Answer (score 3):

```
while (p = false) // obvious error ...
```

If you don't find it : it's `==` not `=` that you want.

Answer (score 3):

change it to while `(false == p)`

Basically here is what happens in order:

1. p is assigned false
2. p is converted to bool

When you says `(p = false)`, 'p' is assigned the value 'false'. After this, the boolean condition of the while loop tests for the value of 'p' which is now `false`, and the loop is never entered.

Answer (score 3):

Since your compiler doesn't seem to be warning you about it, you should either find out how to turn on the warning, or learn the habit of using "Yoda-conditions":

```
while (false = p)
```

will cause a compile error.

Comment: yoda conditions are terrible from a readability point of view. Much better here is `while (!p)`.

Comment: @Alexandre: Fair enough for booleans, but in general my point stands. If you can't get the compiler to warn you, you should program defensively.

Comment: @Alexandre: `while (not p)` is more readable again :-).  Figure 24.3 in the Standard.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the `while (p = false)` to `while (p == false)`.

Explanation: In C/C++, `=` assigns a property, whereas `==` compares values. What you are basically doing here is assigning `false` to `p`. The while loop then checks the value of the expression, which is `p`, which equals `false`, so doesn't run.